# Lua: '<name>' expected near '('

Tags: lua

I've trying to modify some lua files and this particular one shows me an error compiling `luajit: .\decoded\resources\scripts\app\clover_bg.lua:496: '<name>' expected near '('`

```lua
slot1 = {
    SetNodeCategory = function (slot0, slot1)
        function (slot0)
            slot0:setCategory(uv0)

            for slot4 in iterate_children(slot0) do
                uv1(slot4)
            end
        end(slot0)
    end
}
```

Since this is part of the original code from the file, how can i fix the function(slot0)?

ps: line 496 is `function (slot0)`

Comment: Looks like a bug in decompiler.  You should wrap inner function in parentheses (from `function` at line 496 to `end` at line 502)

Answer (score 0):

You can either wrap the innter function's definition in parentheses as Egor suggested or remove it altogether, directly executing the inner function's code.

```lua
slot1 = {
    SetNodeCategory = function (slot0, slot1)
        slot0:setCategory(uv0)

        for slot4 in iterate_children(slot0) do
            uv1(slot4)
        end
    end
}
```